# How to generate case sensitive fields in java from wsdl using cxf-codegen-plugin?

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm using `cxf-codegen-plugin` and try to generate java from wsdl.
In my xsd schema I have following element

```
<xsd:element name="SomeElement">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
        </xsd:attribute>
        <xsd:attribute name="Version" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

CXF tries to generate both attributes into field `version` and throws exception that property already exists.
Is there any way to generate properties as they described in XML? e.g.

```
protected String version;
protected String Version;
```

I know, that I can define binding and rename one of the properties, but I have ~100 wsdl, so I don't want write bindings for each file.

I also tried to add `-autoNameResolution` argument, but it didn't help.

Comment: Good question! Still no answer?

Comment: @Momo, thank you! Unfortunately, no. Finally, I wrote bindings for each wsdl and it was boring.

Comment: I seems that even underscores are ignored. I think i will wrire a xslt on my own to handle that before generate sources